# Preprocess Page Structure

Tags: theming

I'm new to Drupal 8, TWIG, and only a novice at PHP. I'm trying to create a banner section that I can recreate on different pages. I have a banner node section that takes in an image, header, subheader, and link. The structure of the banner will be the same on every template, but obviously the inputs will be different.

I created a preprocess_page function (I think) and then want to call the banner in the template

```
function tibco_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
return array(
    'banner' => array(
        '#theme' => 'tibco_banner',
        '#image' => 'field_banner_image',
        '#header' => 'field_banner_header',
        '#subheader' => 'field_banner_sub_header',
        '#bannerLink' => 'field_banner_link'
    ),
);}
```

The call funciton in the template looks like this

```
{# Banner #}
<div class="full-width">
<div class="row">
{{ tibco_banner }}
</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, nothing is showing up when I do it this way. Have I mixed PHP and TWIG or made a code error?

Comment: Preprocess hooks don't return anything. See the preprocess hooks Drupal has, or any `template_preprocess_*` function.

Comment: This question is a little too broad: You don't say anything about the theme function you are trying to use, including what values it is expecting, or what values you are passing to that theme function.